# pdf extract selected chapter include the selected part of table of contents

Tags: pdf, printing, table-of-contents, self-extracting

If we create a pdf with table of contents we can show this in any pdf viewer eg. Adobe Reader, Firefox etc.

The problem is in some cases you only want a special number of pages of a pdf file include the specific part of the table of contents in this pdf file.

Paid original pdf file with table of content:

[image]

The easy solution is to print the pages of the pdf file with Microsoft print or other tools , save that file as pdf and done.

But now here is my problem because it do not extract the specific part of the table of contents, so you must search into this pdf file for the right chapter.

Printed pdf file with selected chapter but without table of contents:

[image]

For owned word or odt files it's no problem to get the specific parts including the table of content but not by pdf files you have paid for.

Is there any way (windows, linux) to extract the specific selected pages of an paid pdf file include with the selected table of contents?

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by "sites of a pdf file"?

Comment: Sry was a misused word from my side. I mean pages not sites :-)

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to print a subset of the PDF, and would like to include also the Table of Contents? Or just to print the Table of Contents?

Comment: @harrymc  exactly i want to print the subset of a chapter e.g above  "Process and Diagnostic Utilities" include the part of the table of contents of this chapter.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any software that does what you ask. The only solutions I can think of
are:

- Use a PDF editor to truncate the PDF file to the parts you want to print
- Convert the PDF to a document format, such as Word, and do the editing in it

None of these solutions are guaranteed to work for your PDF.
I cannot recommend products for the above, since product recommendations are not
allowed on our site.

Comment: Ok thanks for your reply. Maybe it is a fingerpointer for developers think about it, because physical books have the oppertunity, to put it in a scanner and scan pages. I don´t know how complicated it could be to implement such a feature but the chapter headers are already included (such as a word or open doc file)  in the pdf file so maybe it isn´t so hard to do it. Or add a "reconvert button" in this writing tools :-)

The oppertunities for pdf files are limitless.